# How does Service synchronously communicate with Activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity

1. My application contains a single main Activity and a service.
2. Service will run in background as long as possible even if main Activity is inactive, so I had to launch it with startService() instead of binding them together.
3. There would be many messages and data exchange between Activity and Service while running.
4. I'm planning to use broadIntent() to finish those communication, but you know, intents are all asynchronous. But sometimes synchronous communication is required.

How can I get them synchronously communicated with each other?

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you use binding when your activity is active?

Comment: The SDK said when bind a service with activity, the service will be considered required by the system only for as long as the calling context exists. For example, if this Context is an Activity that is stopped, the service will not be required to continue running until the Activity is resumed.

Comment: Did you mean that I could bind or unbind service at the moment that activity becomes active or inactive?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to look for [bindService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29) and [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html).This lets you open a communication channel between the activity and the service.

Answer (score 0):

what about using LocalBroadcastManager, it will send broadcast from service to local activity only.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html